# R paste() of numeric sequences in Python

Tags: python, r

In R we have easy line that takes numerical sequence and add some prefix string to each:

```
paste0("A", 1:5)
```

In Python things are *waaaaayyy* more complicated:

```
list(map(lambda x:'A'+str(x),list(map(str,range(1,6)))))
```

Is there more elegant way to do it in python?

Comment: @DavidG ok this one is better, but why it cant cast like `'A' + range(1,6)`

Comment: Because that is something called weak typing and it is why javascript is hated by everyone. It is not obvious what it means to add a string and a range. Maybe you want `["A", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['A' + str(i) for i in range (1, 6)]
# ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
```

Answer (score 5):

How about string formatting literals in python 3.6

```
[f'A{i}' for i in range(1, 6)]
```

Output

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
```